# Building in maven with scope as 'provided' in a dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have a `pom` file with several dependencies. One of the dependencies causing error is as follows:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.test.test2</groupId>
   <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

I have the `jar` file of the above dependency on my local machine. When I run the command `mvn clean install` it fails with the following error:

```
27266 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:analyze-only (analyze-used-library) on project my-project: Dependency problems found -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:analyze-only (analyze-used-library) on project hue-com-ifx-dto: Dependency problems found
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Dependency problems found
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.analyze.AbstractAnalyzeMojo.execute(AbstractAnalyzeMojo.java:260)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
```

Where exactly should I provide the jar when the scope is `provided`?

#### EDIT

When I run the command `mvn dependency:analyze-only`

```
7618 [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:analyze-only (default-cli) @ hue-com-ifx-dto ---
8679 [WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
8688 [WARNING]    com.test.test2:some-artifact:jar:17.02-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

Comment: What is the custom `maven-dependeed-library` plugin doing? Furthermore, use of the `org.apache.maven.plugins` group id is strongly discouraged as it should be reserved for the plugins maintained by the Maven team itself.

Comment: @Tunaki sorry, I now modified the error message.

Comment: The Analysis error is I bet somewhere else in the output. Can you show the whole maven run (maybe as a temporary gist).

Comment: You cut out the part of the logs showing the warnings (treated as errors here). There should be log lines with `Used undeclared dependencies found` or `Unused declared dependencies found`.

Comment: @Tunaki There seem to be no other errors. Please check the edit.

Comment: @user3288346 Are you sure you declared your dependency in the dependencies section of your pom? Could you please post your pom?

Comment: "I have the jar file of the above dependency on my local machine." What path?

Comment: It's at a random location in my PC. Should I be putting it under `~/.m2/repository` or is it possible to specify the path?